# How to include a loading spinner in an angular application?

Tags: angular, typescript, progress-bar, angular-material

I am trying to add a spinner to my application but the spinner is not appearing.

There are no errors appearing in the console or terminal, yet the spinner is not appearing.

### loader.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable()
export class LoaderService {
public status: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

display(value: boolean) {
    this.status.next(value);
}
}
```

### app.module.ts

imported LoadService and added it to the providers array

### app.component.ts

```
import { LoaderService } from './services/loader.service';

export class AppComponent {
  //for the spinner
  showLoader: boolean;
  //LoaderService is for the spinner
  constructor(private loaderService: LoaderService) { }
  //for the spinner
  ngOnInit() {
    this.loaderService.status.subscribe((val: boolean) => {
      this.showLoader = val;
    });
  }
}
```

### app.component.html

```
<router-outlet>
<div *ngIf="showLoader">
<mat-spinner></mat-spinner>
</div>
</router-outlet>
```

### custom.component.ts

```
import { LoaderService } from '../services/loader.service';

export class SurveyresultsComponent implements OnInit {

 constructor(private loaderService: LoaderService) { }

 ngOnInit() {
  //http call starts
  this.loaderService.display(true);
  //http call ends
  this.loaderService.display(false);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are calling your loader service in wrong way.

your loader code logic is

```
this.loaderService.display(true);
//http call ends
this.loaderService.display(false);
```

written in custom.component.ts and your HTML code for that is written in app.component.html

try using the same HTML code in custom.component.html or try adding

```
this.loaderService.display(true);
//http call ends
this.loaderService.display(false);
```

this logic in app.component.ts or else you could print showLoader value besides that div in app.component.html like {{showLoader}}

Comment: I added the div component to the custom.component.html but even then it didn't appear. I have been following the steps of this link https://hassantariqblog.wordpress.com/2017/03/22/angular2-using-custom-loader-spinner-as-service-in-angular-2-application/

Comment: after printing showLoader value what is it? have you added the right CSS?

Comment: then there should be a problem with <mat-spinner></mat-spinner> have you tried printing the showLoader  value what is it? or else try removing <mat-spinner></mat-spinner> and add only text like LOADING in that div and check if it is working or no.

Comment: I replaced it by `<router-outlet>
    <div *ngIf="showLoader" class="loading">{{showLoader}}</div>
</router-outlet>` this.

Comment: try replacing this  <span *ngIf="showLoader" class="loading"></span>{{showLoader}}

Comment: Yet no changes. Also the article I mentioned includes Material Module and that has changed now. We no longer have to import Material Module but have to import each module separately like MatProgressSpinnerModule etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165612/discussion-between-hrishikesh-kale-and-steve-doson).

Comment: if you found this helpful you can mark this as an answer so that it will be helpful for others.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a scope issue. An instance of the AppComponent must be available for the subscribe function to use the component's variables. 'this' refers to the scope of the subscribe function.

```
export class AppComponent {
    //for the spinner
    showLoader: boolean;
    //LoaderService is for the spinner
    constructor(private loaderService: LoaderService) { }

    //for the spinner
     ngOnInit() {
         let self=this;

         this.loaderService.status.subscribe((val: boolean) => {
            self.showLoader = val;
         });
     }
}
```

Comment: no brother the issue was on ngOnIt in custom.component.ts file where he tried calling the function twice with true value first and false value after that so by default showLoader value was setting it to false.

Answer (score 0):

In your Custom.component.ts class, you are calling below 2 statements one after the another, instead you have to use timeout

```
ngOnInit() {
  //http call starts
  this.loaderService.display(true);
  //http call ends
  setTimeout(() => {
            this.loaderService.display(false);
          },5000);
  
 }
```

By executing this block, spinner will displayed for 5 Seconds.